# Setting up wildcard subdomain on another subdomain (Namecheap)

Tags: dns, subdomain

My domain name looks like `subdomain.example.com` which points to a server with dedicated IP. What I am trying to do is be able to have `* (wildcard).subdomain.example.com` but so far without success. Here is what I tried:

`A record` `*.subdomain` as host, and value is the `server IP`. But it does not work.

I'm trying to have a wildcard to auto resolve domains like:

```
abc.subdomain.example.com
xyz.subdomain.example.com
```

Should I use A record or CNAME? `subdomain.example.com` is the server's domain and it has its own dedicated IP.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup a wildcard CNAME on namecheap.com. It might be a new feature but I'm not sure.

For example, I have a CNAME record for `subdomain.example.com` pointed at a cloudfront distribution.

For the wildcard, I have another CNAME record, with the host specified as `*.subdomain.`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CNAME Record     |    subdomain      |  d20b3x2oef078.cloudfront.net
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CNAME Record     |    *.subdomain.   |  d20b3x2oef078.cloudfront.net
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NOTE the period `.` at the end of the host name.

It may be possible to simply do `*.` but I have not tried that yet.

Wildcard A Records are also possible, you simply remove the trailing period:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
A Record         |    *.subdomain    |  34.245.102.8
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're pointing to an IP, it should be an A record.
From my understanding, your configuration should be working. Perhaps a limitation on Namecheap? Try Cloudflare. They have stated that they support *.subdomain.domain.com:

> Note, wildcards are only valid in the left most label. For example, it's not possible to add sub.*.example.com, but it's possible to add *.sub.example.com.
>   [[Source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826-Does-Cloudflare-support-wildcard-DNS-entries-)]